# How can I synchronize(submit) my local folder with depot, when I have lots of redundant files deleted manually from workspace,

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have never used P4 version control system before, and just come across with following problem:

I was submitted a project to server with lots of redundant files and have been  working on the project actively. Now I have my project working and clean, and want to synchronize with depot. The problem is that I have deleted lots of files manually in windows file explorer(from my workspace),ignoring the rules of p4(mark for deletion, submit etc.).
How can I synchronize my project with depot? With another word, how can I delete files from depot that I have manually deleted from local folder, which are not shown in "workspace" tab.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command:

```
p4 reconcile
```

This will automatically scan your entire workspace for added/deleted/modified/renamed files and open them for the appropriate actions.  Once you've run `reconcile` you can just `p4 submit` as normal, and everything you did in your workspace should get submitted to the depot.

If you're using P4V, I think there's a "Reconcile..." menu command that will do something similar.